# React without Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor

First of all, I like Meteor but now that I'm learning React I was wondering if it is possible to pull data like Meteor does, only with React. The point is that I'm a bit minimalist and wanted to use less libraries / frameworks as possible, all around React.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple approach would be to use [fetch](https://github.github.io/fetch/). You can also look into other, more versatile options like [SuperAgent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/). Here's a basic example combining React and fetch:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { user: {} };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    fetch('http://reqres.in/api/users/2')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
      }).then(function(body) {
        console.log(body.data);
        self.setState({
          user: body.data
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.state.user.first_name} {this.state.user.last_name}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Keep in mind that you might need to include a [polyfill for fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) depending on which browsers you want to support.

---

Here's the same request with SuperAgent for comparison:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { user: {} };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    superagent
      .get('http://reqres.in/api/users/2')
      .end(function(err, res) {
        console.log(res.body.data);
        self.setState({ user: res.body.data })
      });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.state.user.first_name} {this.state.user.last_name}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/superagent/2.3.0/superagent.min.js"></script>

<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not understand using fetch I can go to mongodb and put the data requests in real time?

Comment: Please give us more details. You want to pull data from a database in node.js? Or on the client? If you want to get data on the client you need a RESTful API.

Comment: Sorry, i just want to get data from mongodb like Meteor does and provide to the client in real time

Comment: Alright, that's a more complex task. Try accessing the database (mongodb) on the server with [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) and then provide that data via an [express API](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) to the client. Then you can use the code in my example to access that data in React. StackOverflow is not a place for free coding services, so please try out some things and come back with specific questions or problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a full stack platform like Meteor to fetch data from web services. You can take a look at XMLHttpRequest (AJAX). It looks strange first when implementing in plain JavaScript but is widely supported.

Another option (that I highly recommend) is using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Fetch is a native way for your browser to make HTTP requests. You even get the power of promises out of fetch. However it isn't supported by all browser out there yet, especially the older ones.

Maybe you can use some polyfills like whatwg-fetch to support older browsers.

Comment: I'm not understand using fetch I can go to mongodb and put the data requests in real time?

Comment: You first need to provide your MongoDB data at a HTTP resource, possibly with nodejs from where you can fetch with your client.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to call your data directly out of your MongoDB, then stick with Meteor, because that is what it is supposed to do.